# Emacs: error wrong number of arguments when trying to call my function

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to make a function that moves to the end of line and inserts a newline.

```
(defun newline-below ()
    (interactive)
    (move-end-of-line)
    (newline)
)
```

However, I get a cryptic error when I try to run it.

```
newline-below: Wrong number of arguments: #[(arg) "
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function `move-end-of-line` needs an argument (try <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> while the cursor is over the function). Just `nil` might work for your purpose:

```
(move-end-of-line nil)
```

Comment: Handy trick: `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`. Now run your function, and you'll get a stack trace showing exactly where the error is coming from. See `M-: (info "(elisp) Debugger")` for details of how to use the debugger.

Comment: One more handy trick: M-x eldoc-mode - when your point is inside a function you can see the required and optional arguments